# Request URL in Javascript, Fetch URL Content using Java Applet, return to Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, url, curl, permissions

I'm in the process of making a little experiment, it grabs a YouTube page, and returns the highest quality MP4 link, then plays this in a HTML 5 Video element.

---

Now I was using PHP with cURL to get the URL content (YouTube), but that only works on my local server (MP4 link is locked to IP address). I can't think of any other way to get the page content due to cross domain rules except a Java applet.

So I've built a Java applet that should return the content of a URL.

**Java**

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
//import java.net.SocketPermission;
//import java.net.URLDecoder;
//import java.net.URLEncoder;
//import java.util.Locale;
//import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class URLFetcherabc extends Applet
{
public String URLContent = "Currently empty";

 public void init()
 {
    System.out.println("Ready to recieve URL");
 }
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
       g.drawString("Java loaded.", 0, 10);
 }
  public void start()
  {
       String container = getURL("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ0AFriC7ZM&Bingbv", "GET"); //<-- This works
       System.out.println(container); //<-- This works
       URLContent = container;
  }
  public void bingo()
    {
      String container = getURL("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ0AFriC7ZM&Bingbv", "GET"); 
       System.out.println(container); 
      URLContent = container;
  }

  public String getURL(String url, String httpMethod)
  {
    try
    {
      URL u = new URL(url);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
      conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
      InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      for (int bytesRead = 0; (bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
      URLContent = output.toString();
      return URLContent;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }return null;
  }


}
```

Now I've got my applet on my page, if I run the method getURL in start() it will return the URL content correctly, but, if I call the getURL method from Javascript like this

**Javascript**

```
var URLFetcherApplet = document.getElementById('URLFetcher');
  URLFetcherApplet.bingo();
```

Which calls Bingo() in Java then I get an error in the Java console.
"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.youtube.com:80 connect,resolve)
null"

So if I run the same method on start(), then it works, but if I try and access it through Javascript it fails, any ideas as to why its doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are able to actually get the URL in Java without signing? I believe the cross-domain rules apply for unsigned applets.

Comment: The applet is signed, it does fetch the source of a URL correctly as I have tested this by printing the source to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing for sure: you have an empty catch block, so you are swallowing any exceptions, hiding them. Since you say the function is returning null, the most probable scenario is that an exception happens somewhere inside the try-catch block. Change the code to:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

and see what comes up on the java console.

**Edit:** If you are not ready to listen to good advice, don't ask questions. I am 99.999% sure that the fault is indeed in your java code (no matter what you say in the comment) and that adding a proper error reporting will give you the real answer in an instant. Add the throw new RuntimeException(e) and look at the console.

My bet is that you will see some kind of "unauthorized operation" error, because probably your applet is not signed (at least you did not write anything about it) and therefore same origin policy still applies (if it didn't apply for unsigned applets, Java would be one great gaping security hole).

If it turns out I am right, I hope you accept my answer even if you consider me rude :-)

**Second Edit:** I checked your code (pasted into Netbeans, little edit, compiled) and it works perfectly (firefox, explorer - both on windows) AND your symptoms seem to shift (you either say it returns null, or that it returns undefined, or that you are not able to call it at all) - I've got one last idea. A common mistake people make is to call objects (like applets or flash) before they are really loaded. At what stage are you executing your javascript? Are you sure the applet is loaded? What if you add a timeout (a couple of seconds) or execute the function from an "onclick" on some button? does anything change? What browser are you using? what is your javascript? what operating system? which plugin version? Unless we can reproduce the problem, we cannot help.

**Third Edit:** (after some experiments by question's author); wrap the javascript call into a PriviledgedAction, for example like this:

```
public String callFromJs(final String url, final String method){

return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PriviledgetAction<String>(){
    public String run(){
        return getUrl(url, method);
    }
});
}
```

and don't swallow exceptions :-)

Comment: Java doesn't give an errors, I think theres an issue with calling the Applets methods with the Javascript as its now giving errors: "TypeError: Result of expression 'URLFetcher.getURL'[undefined] is not a function."

Comment: The Javascript calls URLFetcher.getURL(urltofetch) but the Applet method is getURL(String url, String httpMethod).

Comment: I've changed it to "var result = URLFetcher.getURL(urltofetch, "GET");" but its still saying its not a function, am I targeting the applet correctly?

Comment: The javascipt should be: document.getElementById('URLFetcher').getUrl('http://www.google.pl','GET')

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me (sort of - it throws exception because the applet is unsigned, but this is a different matter :)

Comment: Thanks for you help, the applet is signed on my end, it asks for trust and can run the getURL function if its included in the init() and output the result onscreen, but I want to be able to call the method in Javascript instead of outputting it onscreen. I've tried this: "var result = document.URLFetcher.getURL('http://www.youtube.com','GET');
  alert(result);", it loads the content (it outputs it into the console), but the variable 'result' is just 'undefined'?

Comment: Ok I've updated the code above to what I currently now have. Addressing your questions, I'm calling the javascript function fetchurl('http://youtube.com'); on a button click once the Java applet has loaded. I'm using Safari 5.0.3 on OSX, I have tried Firefox on Windows XP and still it does not work. Currently with the code I have above, it just returns undefined.

Comment: Its returning undefined in Safari OSX, and null under Windows in Firefox, I have tried directly accessing the URLContent variable via "var URLContent = URLFetcherApplet.URLContent; alert(URLContent);", and it just outputs "Currently empty", so the getURL method isn't actually being run(?) otherwise this would be different from the initial value of "Currently empty".

Comment: Ok I've tweaked it a little now I'm getting "java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.youtube.com:80 connect,resolve)" even though just for testing I'm signing with this policy "grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
", any ideas?

Comment: hey, we are getting somewhere :-) out of curiosity: what was the "little tweaking"? And you have written before that you have actually seen the data being read by the applet... so did you see it and now it stopped?

Comment: I was just about to ask about doPrivileged and you'd already done it, Thanks for all your help, and for being extremely patient :)

Comment: Sorry for not giving the full answer right away and thanks for the credits. It's just that I got snappish when you (at first) ignored my good advice about exception and - without checking - insisted that it was javascript's fault :-D Oh, well, I had a really bad day. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  get the XML object
function get_xml_object() {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        alert('Your browser does not support AJAX.');
        return null;
    }
}

//  fetch url
function fetch_url(whichurl) {
    var myobj=get_xml_object();
    myobj.open("GET",whichurl,false);
    myobj.send();
    return myobj.responseText;
}
```